# pyexcelerator: how to delete a excel-sheet by sheet-name

Tags: python, excel, pyexcelerator

As titled, I'm using **pyexcelerator** to operate excel files.

Code:

```
from pyExcelerator import parse_xls
fpath='D:\\Capacity_20120811.xls'
eData=parse_xls(fpath)




>>> eData
[(u'testExcelReport_hr',
  {(0, 0): u'Deletetime',
   (0, 1): u'Food',
   (0, 2): u'Peak Rate',
   (0, 3): u'Total Bytes',
   (0, 4): u'Total Msg No',
   (1, 0): u'20110824T05',
   (1, 1): u'111BSA',
   (1, 2): 6255326.0,
   (1, 3): 16226057.0,
   (1, 4): 127.0,
   (2, 0): u'20110824T06',
   (2, 1): u'111BSA',
   (2, 2): 352978.0,
   (2, 3): 672104.0,
   (2, 4): 2124.0})]
```

I want delete sheet by `sheetname:'testExcelReport_hr'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension for that:

```
eData = [(sheet_name, sheet_data) for (sheet_name, sheet_data) in eData
         if sheet_name != u'testExcelReport_hr']
```

This keeps all sheets except for the one named `testExcelReport_hr`, in effect removing that sheet.

Comment: @Kevin: You will have to export the workbook back into an XLS file. I thought you were just asking how to do it in memory.

Comment: @Kevin: I'm sorry, I don't know how to. I haven't ever actually used pyExcelerator, I just took a look at the structure of `eData`.